# I deleted /etc/nginx by mistake. How to fix this?

Tags: 12.04, nginx

I deleted `etc/nginx` by mistake and now i am stuck. I tried compiling by source and repository but didn't get it back. Some please help me asap to fix this problem. A detail explanation will be most appreciated.

Comment: Your settings are gone, but I believe you can purge and reinstall. `sudo apt-get purge nginx*` then, `sudo apt-get install nginx`

Comment: Not working mate.Any other suggestion?

Comment: Try, `dpkg-reconfigure nginx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the obvious course of action is:

1. restore from backup

   - best option here: have `etckeeper` installed and configured and running and restore the latest configuration ... depending on the backend for `etckeeper` make sure that you clone it to another machine, i.e. include it in your backup strategy.
2. Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure nginx`
3. reinstall the `nginx` package after purging it, thus restoring the default configuration. Make *sure* to `purge`, not just to `remove`.

To reiterate: `etckeeper` is a convenient and unified frontend to various distributed version control systems. You should use it to protect yourself from disaster and keep an off-site backup of the underlying repository.

Comment: Both solutions don't work for me